Conda options do not need to be written up to the end
It seems that you do not need to fully write an option to a conda command.
For example you could write
conda install numpy --dr

or
conda install numpy --dry-r

and both these commands would be equivalent to
conda install numpy --dry-run

on the other hand if you write
conda install numpy --drgvwfgv

then you get an error.
I find this behavior quite odd and maybe a bit dangerous. Is this expected?

conda uses argparse to parse command line arguments. This allows by default:

allow_abbrev - Allows long options to be abbreviated if the abbreviation is unambiguous. (default: True)

So this is expected behaviour. I don't really see, how this is "dangerous" because it only works when you actually write a unique prefix of a long argument.
Whether or not this is "odd" is of course personal opinion, but seems to be generally acceptable enough that it is the default of pythons built-in argument parser

Thx! So this is rather an argparse question. This is to me clearly "dangerous" since you could misspell an option and end up with the abbreviation of another option...
